# Check if elements in array are using ASCII code

Tags: javascript, arrays, ascii

I have the following array and I was wondering if there is a way to scan it and get any ASCII codes contained inside an element.

The array looks something like this:

`var elem = ["Joe", "M"+String.fromCharCode(13)+"ry", "Element_03", "Element_04"];`

Attempted using a `for loop` to scan through the array and conditionally check each element for ASCII code but I couldn't come up with anything.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking- what output do you want, given an input of that `elem` variable?

Comment: You're trying to find stuff like String.fromCharCode(13)? correct?

Comment: Couple of things... all the text in your array's are ASCII characters.  I think you are mistaking the terminology in your question.   Are trying to scan each element for certain special ASCII characters?  For instance, do you want to find any non alphanumeric characters?

Comment: @mrbinky3000 Actually, JavaScript—like Java, .NET, …—uses the UTF-16 encoding of the Unicode character set. See [String.fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode). This makes sense because all text in HTML (and XML) is from the [Unicode charcter set](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
var hash={};
elem.forEach(function(str){
  for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++){
    hash[str.charCodeAt(i)]=true;
  }
});
console.log(Object.keys(hash));
```

Simply iterate over the array and chars, and add each char code into a hash table.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to find non-alphanumeric characters in each string of the array.  For example, CharCode 13 is a carriage return.  Depending on what you consider to be "special"  this might work.

```
var elem = ["Joe", "M"+String.fromCharCode(13)+"ry", "Element_03", "Element_04"];

var codesFound = {};

elem.join('').split('').forEach(char => {
  var code = char.charCodeAt(0);
  if ( code < 32 || code > 126 ) {
    codesFound[code] = true;
  }
});

console.log(Object.keys(codesFound));
```

I'm using this table as a guide.  But you can get the just from my code.
http://www.asciitable.com/